# Fetch data from api with graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to connect to a website and they have given me :

```
Url: https://api.demo...
headers:"x-api-key" and "x-api-user"
```

I do not know how to make the connection with them,I tried the code below:

```
const query = ` 
query {
   some query here
    }
`;
const url = ``

const opts = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "x-api-key": ,
    "x-api-user": , },
  body: JSON.stringify({ query })
};
```

Is this the right way? when I run it `npm start=> App Crashes` I am new to javascript and I dont even know how to make the search in google,can someone please guide me to a tutorial,link or please respond with the right way?

**Thank you for your understanding**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the fetch call.

```
const query = `query {
  Some query
}`;
 
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query
  })
})
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => console.log('data returned:', data));
```

Comment: That's going to throw a reference error because `fetch` isn't defined.

Comment: @Quentin did you close my question?Please this is not the same...where do i put my credentials?

Comment: @Quentin can you please let me know,I have had not a response